# NuGet update and conditional references

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

Our nupkg packages contain multiple versions of the same dll (x86, x64, AnyCPU) and in the csproj files, in references I use conditional references to pick a specific dll depending on the current platform set. As a result I have multiple references to the same library (just different platform compilation).

here's a fragment of my csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="xxxx" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x86'">            
   <HintPath>..\..\packages\xxxx.2.7.0.1093\lib\net45\x86\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="xxxx" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\xxxx.2.7.0.1093\lib\net45\x64\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="xxxx" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='AnyCPU'">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\xxxx.2.7.0.1093\lib\net45\AnyCPU\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This construction works very well in both MSBuild and in Visual Studio.

Unfortunately after *nuget update* the csproj references get messed up. Here's the result:

```
<Reference Include="xxxx" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x86'">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\xxxx.2.7.0.1093\lib\net45\x86\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="xxxx" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\xxxx.2.7.0.1093\lib\net45\x64\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="xxxx">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\xxxx.2.7.0.1094\lib\net45\x86\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

So looks like only one reference got updated and... the *Condition* section got dropped as well as the first dll on the list was used.

Not what I was expecting. Any ideas how to best work around that problem? Anyone using conditional references in your csproj's with nuget? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nuget does voodoo to the .csproj references. The above is yet another reason I would like nuget packages at a SOLUTION level...and to be versionless.  And let me control the versioning with the build-number ranges.  I come from a java/ivy world.......which allows you to do handle binary-dependencies at a solution-level.  I don't think you'll find a resolution, but hopefully I'm wrong and somebody will chime in.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid you are right and the approach we are thinking of taking is to update the csproj files ourselves as part of the MSBuild "nuget-update" target. I was hoping someone would know a better way :/

Solution level dependencies make sense, especially in a situation when it's a bad idea to refer two different versions of the same DLL in one application. With project level dependencies it's quite easy to do.

Comment: I "get" that project-level dependencies situations could arise...but solution-level dependency management seems much more mainstream to me and project-level dependencies are more fringe cases.  I'm not sure why nuget missed that boat.........but I'm not the sharpest knife in the drawer either.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, we ended up just parsing and regex'ing the csproj file after nuget update and fixing what needed to be fixed. I wasn't able to find any better solution than that.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 8):

Nuget lets you deploy a .targets file that is automatically included in your project (see [Nuget docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package)). Yo you can include the conditional references in the custom targets file and deploy the dlls in the tools folder of the package so they are not added as references by Nuget automatically.

Lets assume your package is named 'PackageWithConditionalReferences'. The folder structure your nuget package is created from could look like this:

```
tools
    lib\net45\x86\xxxx.dll
    lib\net45\x64\xxxx.dll
    lib\net45\AnyCPU\xxxx.dll
build
    PackageWithConditionalReferences.targets
```

where PackageWithConditionalReferences.targets has content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>    
    <MyLibDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\net45</MyLibDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="xxxx", Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(MyLibDir)\x64\xxxx.dll</HintPath>   
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="xxxx", Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(MyLibDir)\x86\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="xxxx", Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(MyLibDir)\AnyCPU\xxxx.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Make sure your .targets file is named liked the package. After installing the package a restart of VisualStudio is neccessary for the references to get visible (tested with VisualStudio 2015).