# How can we use managed nuget packages in c++/cli project

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I want to consume managed nuget package in c++/cli project. Is there a way to do that?

For example my scenario is almost like this:

I have created a C# project(MainProject) and added EntityFramework nuget package to that project.

I have created one more C# project(TestCSProject) and added MainProject as reference to that project. Then automatically in references entityframework is also added

I have created one C++/CLI project(TestCLIProject) and added MainProject as reference to that project so that I want to see whether I can use entityframework.

But that didnt happened.

So I want to know how can I use managed nuget package in c++/cli project

Comment: Yes I have added using namespace System::Data::Entity(Presented in EntityFraneowrk.dll) in my C++/CLI project. It shows error saying that it is not there.

Comment: Nuget doesn't support C++/CLI projects, the package manager for C++ projects is vcpkg.  Don't bother.  One trick you could use is add a dummy C# project to the solution and use its Nuget support to get the library.  Which you did, make sure to build the C# project so you can use Project > Add Reference > Browse to select the library.

Comment: Means Adding Nuget package to dummy c# project and then  manually add all the references to c++/cli project? It will be cumbersome right in case nuget package depends on few more nuget packages and if we have so many dlls to refer? @HansPassant

Comment: It is C++, if it wasn't cumbersome then everybody would use it.  Do keep in mind that C++/CLI was primarily meant to make interop with native code easy to do, that's a million miles removed from doing anything with databases.  Moving the non-interop related code into a C# library is a sensible thing to do.

Comment: I have used EntityFramework as an example here. My C++/CLI is not related to any DB operations. In C++/CLI project I need to use classes which are present in an assembly that is in managed nuget package

Comment: @HansPassant I have created a dummy c# project and added my nuget package which depends on few more nuget packages. Now I built the dummy c# project. Whatever assemblies are there in bin folder I'm planning to refer them in c++/cli project. Is there a way to automatically add assemblies in bin folder as reference to c++/cli project?

This will help me alot

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already doing that. To glue between C# and C++ I need to this where I'm blocked.

Answer (score 7):

C++/CLI project can use nuget packages using `packages.config` (in VS2019 still there is no PackageReference support for C++,  [PackageReference for NuGet packages in C++ projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599104/packagereference-for-nuget-packages-in-c-projects)). As pointed in the comments, C++/CLI should be used for interop with native code only. Anyway there may be a need sometime to use nuget packages here.

In Visual Studio 2019 the following worked for me for a C++ project referencing .Net Framework:

1. Go to package manager console: `Tools` -> `NuGet Package Manager` -> `Package Manager Console`. Then install nuget package(s) ([instruction from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell)). E.g. EF nuget installation could be like:

> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.4.4 -ProjectName TestCLIProject

After nuget installation a `packages.config` file will be created in the project's folder and added to the project. E.g. after EF nuget installation packages.config could be like:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <packages>
>     <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="native" />
> </packages>
> ```

2. Add reference(s) to dll(s) from the nuget. `Project` -> `Add Reference...` -> `Browse...` -> locate solution's folder -> go to `packages` folder -> go to nuget's folder -> locate dll(s)

For example for EF this resulted as .vcxproj was updated with:

```
  <Reference Include="EntityFramework">
    <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
    <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

3. Project is ready for build. If Visual Studio has opted out `Tools` -> `Options` -> `NuGet Package Manager` -> `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio`, then nugets could be manually restored e.g. in Package Manager Console with `Update-Package` command.

Answer (score 6):

With the newest Version of VS2022 (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3) you can now as well use PackageReference in your C++/CLI project. Just make sure you have added

`<EnableManagedPackageReferenceSupport>true</EnableManagedPackageReferenceSupport>`

to the PropertyGroup with `Label="Globals"` in your .vcxproj file. Furthermore please be aware that your C++/CLI project must be targeting .NET Core or .NET 5+. As you can read in the [Release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.3) this doesn't work (and neither is it planned to be supported in the future) for C++/CLI projects targeting .NET Framework.

With this enabled you can now also use the NuGet Package Manager by

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click "References" and
2. choose "Manage NuGet Packages"

just like it is described in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio#nuget-package-manager).

Comment: Good news, works.